# Interpreting relative paths as paths to the production server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, path

How do I tell my local server to interpret all relative paths, that start with a `/uploads/`, from a remote server (the production server)?

The `uploads` folder is out of version control and I don't have it in my local server (the testing server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) module of apache.

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /uploads http://live.domain.com/uploads
ProxyPassReverse /uploads http://live.domain.com/uploads
```

The `ProxyRequests Off` disables forward proxy so your machine can't be used as a proxy server.

The `<Proxy *>...</Proxy>` sets the access rights to your (Reverse-)Proxy; 'all' in this case.

And finaly the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` define that every request to '/uploads' should be passed on to 'http://live.domain.com/uploads' (->ProxyPass) and every response from 'http://live.domain.com/uploads' should be treated as it would be from '/uploads' (->ProxyPassReverse).

Comment: Could you add comments to explain in brief the different parts of the code?

Comment: @Emanuil: Added a basic explanation, for further information please visit the provided link.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. Should the code be inside the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Honestly I don't know if it works in the .htaccess; I'm using it in the vHost.conf/httpd.conf, but goolge/http://www.phwinfo.com/forum/alt-apache-configuration/325206-why-proxypassreverse-not-allowed-htaccess.html says you can't us it in the .htaccess, but just try it....

Comment: It worked! Thanks again! As to the `.htaccess`, putting the code inside of it results in a server error.